# Having trouble understanding this integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm dealing with the integral $$\int_0^{2\pi}cot(e^{it})ie^{it}dt$$ Initially it seemed quite obvious that this equals $\log(\sin(e^{it})|_0^{2\pi}=\log(\sin(1))-\log(\sin(1))=0$ as $e^0=e^{2i\pi}=1$.  But Wolfram Alpha says this integral evaluates $2\pi i$.

Comment: Does it help if you know that $z = e^{it}$ assuming $|z|=1$?

Comment: There's a zero in there in a hidden denominator... Residue theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral is the same as the contour integral $\oint_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \cot\, z\, dz$, which is $2\pi i\operatorname{Res}_{z = 0} \cot z$ by the residue theorem. We have

$$\cot z = \frac{\cos z}{\sin z} = \frac{1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + O(z^4)}{z\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} + O(z^4)\right)} = \frac{1}{z}\left(1 +O(z^2)\right) = \frac{1}{z} + O(z)$$

The residue $\operatorname{Res}_{z = 0} \cot z$ is therefore equal to $1$ and the value of the integral is $2\pi i$.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question, the flaw in your argument is that $\log$ is not single valued on the complex domain. $2\pi i$ is exactly how much $\ln$ changes as it takes a circuit around the origin.

Comment: Thanks!  We haven't covered Residue Theorem yet in this course, but this answer helped me understand the answer intuitively.